# Wordpress not registering custom options from options.php page

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Frustrated SO regular here:

I'm creating a theme-options.php page for a child theme in Wordpress.  [Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/zcnqbYPF). The page renders correctly, including: Adding the page link to the correct admin menu, creating and displaying the options page.  When I click save, however, it takes me to a 500 (internal server error page).

Using the 'adminer' plugin (phpmyadmin) I have looked at the wp_options table, and there are none of the custome settings/fields that I have specified.  My best guess at the problem is that the settings aren't registering properly so when I post the form to options.php it responds with an error because it doesn't expect those form fields.

I've been wracking my brain around this code for a few days now, and am wondering if someone else can take a look at it for me?  I would really appreciate a few extra eyes...

*Some resources I have tried:*

- http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/
- http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section
- [My settings are not saving in wordpress theme options page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235094/my-settings-are-not-saving-in-wordpress-theme-options-page) (his settings appear empty in db. mine don't appear at all)

Comment: I think you are using the wrong identifier when calling `settings_fields` in your form (#115), it should be the same as the one you use when calling `register_setting` (#24), so 'wsuy_theme_options';

Comment: @Richard M, you beautiful, beautiful man. I can't mark a comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh crud,
It dawned on me after I spent an hour figuring it out that Richard M had given you the answer.

I created a new paste of your code, cleaned up some: http://pastebin.com/enUa3xme

I fixed the issue and also added the function `add_my_options()` and removed the `is_admin()` wrapper around your admin action hooks since they will only be triggered in the admin area, so they are unnecessary.

I needed to learn this since I use a half-way-done implementation of this, so even if it isn't helpful to you, it was worth learning...